# Create multiple new fields from values in other fields on all documents in a MongoDB Collection

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have a couple of data issues on the mongoDB documents in a collection. I'm trying to write an db.collection.updateAll script to update the documents but I can't seem to get it work no matter what I do.

I want to convert a text string stored in data.date from a string:

"data" : {
"date" : "2019-01-07T00:00:00.000Z"
}

Into a an ISO Date.

And I want to take the _id field, and copy it to a field called "id", I know this might seem silly, but there is a bug in some of our reports and I can't get a code update in for a couple of weeks, so making the data available via the "id" and "_id" fields will stop the Service Desk calls until I get a proper fix in.

I had been trying this:

```
db.getCollection("myCollection").updateMany({}, 
    [{
       "$set": {
           { "id" : ["$_id"] } ,
                   "$data.date": {
                     "$dateFromString": {
                        dateString: '$data.date'
                     }
           }
       }
    }]
);
```

But neither field gets set. When I run the two $sets individually I get the following error messages...

When I try and set "id":

```
db.getCollection("myCollection").updateMany(
      {},
      { $set: { "id" : ["$_id"] } }
   );
```

It just sets the value as "$_id" rather than getting the value from the _id field.

If I try and set the date field

```
db.getCollection("myCollection").updateMany(
      {},
      { $set: {  "$data.date": {
                     "$dateFromString": {
                        dateString: '$data.date'
                     }
           } } }
   );
```

I get the error message:

The dollar ($) prefixed field '$data' in '$data' is not valid for storage.

All the examples I could find online show how to set literal values but none seemed to help with getting the new values from the fields themselves.

Comment: what is your mongoDB version ?

Answer (score 0):

Here try this it should work as you are trying to add new fields so use `$addFields`. works in mongoDb 4.2

```
db.test.updateMany({}, 
   [  {
        $addFields:{
           id:'$_id',
           'data.date':{$toDate:'$data.date'}
        }
      }
   ]
)
```